# Downloading Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

Downloading Android SDK and I don't understand this part....

"Append the full path to the tools directory, separating it from the preceding path using a semicolon. Close all dialogs."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your environment variables in Windows. Go to advanced tab in the Computer Management Properties, go to environmental variables click settings. Go to path under system variables. Append to the end of the existing string ; then the path for the tools.

Answer (score 1):

That just means that your PATH variable may contain another paths, so to separate them you just need to put a semicolon between the last path in PATH variable and path you're adding.